# Unwanted character \\\r is appearing in json response from rest api

Tags: java, mysql, json, rest

I have written a few rest services to extract data from a mysql database and display it in json format on **Postman client**. However for some of the response items, I get this unwanted **\\r** character in the response values. For example:

```
{
"colour": "yellow",
"deliveryCharge": 5,
"description": "Mangoes from Ratnagiri",
"keyFeatures": [
  "Seedless\\\r",
  "Ripe and Sweet"
],
"price": 100,
"productId": 49,
"productName": "Alfonso",
"specifications": {
  "entry": [
    {
      "key": "Feature",
      "value": "N/A"
    }
  ]
},
"stock": 20,
"warranty": 1
}
```

How do I get rid of these characters in the final json response? I have tried isolating them using **.replace()** and **.split()** methods for the output strings fetched from the database, but it doesn't work.

Comment: How could we know? You haven't posted any single line of code showing how you generate the JSON. I can just home you're not generating the JSON by appending strings together, and that you're using a JSON library.

Comment: I am automatically generating json format using @produces(APPLICATION_JSON) and @XMLRootElement annotations.

Comment: @whosoever downvoted this : Please do not downvote without without reason. If u have any queries, please ask, I will clarify them. I am new to rest APIs.

Comment: So the string in the database contains these characters. JSON has nothing to do with your problem. It's just that the data contains a trailing \ followed by a \r.

Comment: I downvoted, for a reason. You're asking why something doesn't work as you think it should without posting any code.

Comment: But I am unable to see these characters in my database entries. Many of the object's representations are fine.. just a few have these problems, and it is invisible if I check from mysql workbench :) How do I get rid of them,atleast such that they don't appear in the json output?

Comment: @JBNizet: I did that because its working fine for most responses, doesn't work for some. So I deduced that it is not the code problem, rather it is about something else. Just am not sure what exactly it is :)

Comment: What part of the code do you actually want to see? This is an entire project :)

Comment: Find the entry in the database that has these unwanted characters. Then use a SQL query to update the entry by replacing the value by all its characters minus the last two ones.

Answer (score 2):

You have two escaped character `\` and `\r` in the string. `trim` method in String class can remove `\r` but not `\`. If you don't want to send these character, You will have to do it yourself before serializing the objec to to JSON.

Comment: Yes, how do I do this?

Comment: @SoulRayder You will have to do it where you are serializing the data retrived from database to the json

Comment: json is automatically being formed since I am using annotations of @XmlrOOTeLEMENT, so when do I detect the characters? And how do I remove them. I tried .replace("\\\r","") and .split("\\\r"). Trim didnt work

Comment: Once again, you're telling us that you tried things, wonder why it doesn't work, but fail to post the code. We can't find a bug in code without seeing the code.